# Symfony 4 softdelete with Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony

I want a specific entity to be softdeleted (not all Entities). I've installed the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) bundle which should give me the [Softdeleteable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md) feature.

So I updated my Entity:

**User.php**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false, hardDelete=false)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
```

I created the migration and run the migration. My table `User` now as an extra column `deleted_at`.

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md#usage) I should now be possible to run this code to softdelete a record:

```
public function delete(User $user, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
     $em->remove($user);
     $em->flush();
```

This however throws me an error because the User entity has relations and the User itself cannot be deleted. Sure, this is like I programmed is. But I do not really want to delete the record, I want to softdelete the record.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?' with params [79]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`thedatabase`.`shoppingcart`, CONSTRAINT `FK_932C7444A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

When reading the [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md#setup-and-autoloading), it mentions something about settingup softdelete. But to be honest, I have no clue on how to fix that.

How can I make use of softdelete in Symfony 4?

Comment: How did you installed it? Via Symfony Flex? Or without it?

Comment: I used Symfony Flex

Comment: Did you activate the extension? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/configuration.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want

Comment: @EquaPro, forgot to activate it... Tnx man!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would guess that what you are missing is to enable the extension in the file *config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml* that was added by the flex receipt.

It looks like, [per default](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/11c3e5eac10fd4a59b0458f622b403dc1ecd1960/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle/1.2/config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml), it reads

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
```

When, if you want to use soft deletable, you would need to activate it:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to add `softdeletable: true` to the `stof_doctrine_extensions`. Tnx!!!

Comment: Don't forget the filter feature: https://symfony.com/doc/1.x/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/softdeleteable-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

I also have to include this in my doctrine.yaml

doctrine:
dbal:

## your dbal config here

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
```

## only these lines are added additionally

```
    filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true #this one doesn't was in the doc, I found it in an issue
```